# Should there be different login pages in terms of look and feel of a single company which has multiple products?

Tags: ux-field

I'm evaluating one large application which has different products and each product has unique visual design for its login page. Now though products falls under same company their customers may purchase individual product and not complete suit.

So I think there should be uniformity in terms of design across all the products, though they will be sold individually. Now I still need some opinions on this for better UX. Any valuable insights are welcome.

Comment: This feels a little backwards. It seems you've already drawn your conclusions and you're now looking for opinions that support that conclusion. There are examples of companies that have a unified login like Google. But there are also companies that use different styled login for their products. 37signals didn't have a unified login for their services if i remember correctly. It's all about what the user is expecting.

Answer (score 1):

Your question depends too much on several factors like:

**Branding**
Is it a good or bad thing when a product is associated with the other products or with your brand?

**Usability**
If there was a unified design for the login page and a company uses multiple products, would users be confused about in which application they are logging in?

**Design**
If there was a unified design only for the login page, would it break with the design of the rest of the application?

It is not possible for someone from the outside to answer questions like this without having any inside information.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, you are thinking to implement SSO along all your product login pages since the products come under one umbrella/master brand (much like enterprise solutions). Implementation of uniformity of login/signup page design + functionality will be more appropriate if:

1. Single sign-on (SSO) environment is already there in place for implementation much like Google/Microsoft/Oracle/Yahoo i.e. the user doesn't need to take the pain of entering the username/password everytime the user wants to login to an individual product page.
2. If the individual products/sub-brands showcased/sold are branded along with the umbrella/master brand and are the user is provided relevant info too about the association of the master brand and the sub-brands. Example: Google, Google plus, Google Mail/Gmail, Google browser/Chrome, Google apps, Google Docs, Google Drive, Google Analytics, etc.

[image: Google's SSO page with relevant info]

3. There are appropriate checks and balances to ensure that there are no security loopholes and that authentication protocols are well maintained.
4. User's account page is seamlessly synchronized with appropriate account records, purchase history, invoices across the network.

All said, the easiest route (from operational, cost POV) will be to leave the login pages as is, since your query doesn't implicate that it's sort of mandatory to implement the SSO.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Ramnath! this answer will definitely work for me while taking further decision.

Answer (score 0):

Any research or context (business case, roles, personas, workflows, etc.) on which to base your design assumptions?

I've got no argument whatsoever with consistency and standards, but...
Net/Net:  We *all* want a **customized UI** (the Fewest Clicks to Satisfaction)

You've already indicated that a given customer is likely to explore your products in a 'silo-ed' fashion, which lends itself to such a *customized* approach, rather than one-size-fits-all.

Aside from the *UI issues*, you also have the opportunity to collaborate with marketing folks in crafting an appropriate *pathway*, effective *message*, and compelling *buying experience* for each customer silo.  Cross-selling to your other product & services might be part of that.

PS:
I'm assuming here that a login page is not simply a couple of fields and a button.  There should be some consistency and best practices as regards raw functionality, of course.  But if one product is used by technicians, another by salespeople, and a third by management, then you'll be more effective when you recognize that up front and craft your design accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

There are no strict rules around this. It is completely subjective, you can have the consistent simple login screen for all the products for maintaining the consistency or you can have different designs for each product. Each product login screen can have some design elements or features which talk about the product. The branding guidelines / themes are vital in the designing.